# Salesforce Apex Trigeer

Tags: salesforce

in below code example i want to compare the e-mail and contact number of customer and complaint object. complaint and customer are in lookup relationship. i want output like if before registering a compliant it should check the same e-mail address and phone number must be in customer record.

trigger Demo on Complaint__c (before insert) {

```
if(trigger.isBefore)
{
    if(trigger.isInsert)
    {
        for(Shan__Complaint__c a:Trigger.new)
        {
            for(Shan__bsnl_customer__c b:Trigger.new)
               if(a.Shan__Phone_Number_del__c== b.Shan__cust_contact__c && a.Shan__E_mail_del__c==b.Shan__cust_email__c)
                {
                        a.adderror('Customer is not in Database');

                }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things here. Firstly, if you're only defining this trigger to run before insert, your if statements to check that it is before an insert are redundant.

Secondly, Trigger.new is a collection of objects being inserted, in this case I'm assuming objects of type Shan__Complaint__c, so you won't magically be able to get any other object types out of the collection like you're trying with Shan__bsnl_customer__c here.

What you'll need to do instead is do a query for the relevant Shan__bsnl_customer__c objects and then check them.

Something like this should be enough to get you started. I've used Shan__CustomerId__c for the relationship as you didn't specify it in your question, make sure you substitute it for the real field name. I've also kept the logic in your final if statement as you have put it, although from reading your question and the error message it sounds to me like you want these to be != instead of ==

```
Set<Id> customerIds = new Set<Id>();

for (Shan__Complaint__c complaint : Trigger.new)
{
    //get a list of Customer Ids to query
    customerIds.add(complaint.Shan__CustomerId__c);   // replace field name here
}

//query the customer objects
Map<Id, Shan__bsnl_customer__c> customers = new Map<Id, Shan__bsnl_customer__c>(
    [SELECT Id, Shan__cust_contact__c, Shan__cust_email__c 
      FROM Shan__bsnl_customer__c 
      WHERE Id IN :customerIds];    

for (Shan__Complaint__c complaint : Trigger.new) 
{ 
    //get the right customer -- replace field name with correct value
    Shan__bsnl_customer__c customer = customers.get(complaint.Shan__CustomerId__c);

    //add null check in case no customer found
    if (customer == null ||
         (complaint.Shan__Phone_Number_del__c == customer.Shan__cust_contact__c 
         && complaint.Shan__E_mail_del__c == customer.Shan__cust_email__c))
    {
          complaint.addError('Customer is not in Database');
    }
}
```

I've made the assumption that if no customer is found (eg, the Customer lookup relationship field is blank) then that is also an error state, it seems like that would be the case based on your question.

As I said, I would also review the conditions in your final if statement, they seem to contradict the question, otherwise this code or something similar should accomplish what you want.

I think you would also benefit from some further reading on Triggers, particularly the following:

[Trigger Context Variables](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm)

[Common Bulk Trigger Idioms](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_bulk_idioms.htm)

[Trigger and Bulk Request Best Practices](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_bestpract.htm)

Comment: i want customer lookup field should be blank

Comment: Your original question says that you want to check if the email address and phone number are in the customer record - if you want the customer lookup field to be blank then surely this would always be false?

I'm sorry but I really don't understand what you want when reading it with your original question.

Comment: I want to check details of customer like email and phone number if phone number and email address matches then only customer can regiester a complaint!!!

Comment: Daniel Bernsons  I want to check the customer already exists or not if he exists then only customer can log a complaint